# clarification needed for use of Spring: <aop:scoped-proxy/>

Tags: java, spring

I am learning the use of   tag in spring. I have written a simple prog.

```
    <bean id="book" class="com.test.scoped.Book" scope="prototype" >
    <property name="name" value="DefaultName"></property>
         <aop:scoped-proxy/> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="reader" class="com.test.scoped.Reader" >
        <property name="book" ref="book" />
    </bean>


public class Book {

    private String name;

    public String toString (){
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}


class Reader {
    private Book book;

    public Book getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public void setBook(Book book) {
        this.book = book;
    }

}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ScopedProxy.xml");

        Book firstBook  = ((Reader)ctx.getBean("reader")).getBook();
        System.out.println("First Book : "+firstBook.getName());
        firstBook.setName("Edge of Eternity");
        System.out.println("First Book : "+firstBook.getName());

        Book secondBook = ((Reader)ctx.getBean("reader")).getBook();
        System.out.println("Second Book : "+secondBook.getName());
    }

}
```

> When I run Main class , I get below result :

```
First Book : DefaultName

First Book : DefaultName

Second Book : DefaultName
```

> My Question, why is name of the firstBook not set even though I have set it : firstBook.setName("Edge of Eternity");  . When I remove  aop:scoped-proxy , name is set properly.
>   Why is default name not overwrritten ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use scoped-proxy beans in the way you are doing. Scoped-proxy beans are useful when developing -i.e.- webapps and using them as being referenced from a singleton bean.

Take a look to the Spring documentation [1]: "You do not need to use the <aop:scoped-proxy/> in conjunction with beans that are scoped as singletons or prototypes"

[1] http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection

Answer (score 0):

If your main objective is to set `default value` for the property `name`, then all you need to do is just

```
<bean id="book" class="eu.europa.ema.esubmission.psur.Book" scope="prototype" >
    <property name="name" value="DefaultName"></property>
</bean>
```

Then you can override the property `name` if you wish.

Then regarding the `aop:scoped-proxy` which is completely unrelated for `beans` other than `scope=session` beans.

If you want to inject `Session scope` beans as dependency to other `beans` then only you should use `scoped-proxy` declaration. Since your `Book` bean is defined as `prototype` its not needed.